# Initialize admob with different activity than the one showing it

Tags: android, admob

I noticed that Admob Interstitial takes an activity as a parameter. What if I initialize a public static Interstitial variable in Activity A and display the interstitial in Activity B? Is this a problem? Does the activity parameter matter which one?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it takes an Activity and not a Context then I would strongly suspect that it making some use the user interface context. So creating a static interstitial and switching contexts would be a **bad** idea.